Is there a widely or more commonly-used term that would yield resources for the "fixer mentality"?
I am trying to determine if there is a more commonly used term for the "fixer mentality" or "compulsive fixing," the latter of which seems to incorrectly suggest an OCR connection.
To offer a different definition: the inability to not accept a situation as broken, and to strain to keep working on correcting the issue even when doing so causes tension and negative repercussions.
I cannot find many books about fixer mentality; usually, when I encounter this, I am using the wrong language for something well-covered under its real name.
(As a humorous version of it, I'm reminded of an xkcd: "Come to bed."  "I can't. Somebody is WRONG on the Internet.")
